# Application context from a Grails plugin?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm developing a plugin and trying to properly decouple as much as possible.  How would I get the application context of the grails-app that is including my plugin?  I have a doWithWebDescriptor that is including a servlet which is being included at the main grails-app context:

```
/MainApp/servlet-url-pattern
```

I would like to reference this in the plugin's GSP.  What is the appropriate way?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your `bootstrap.groovy` in `init`

```
ApplicationContext appContext = (ApplicationContext)
servletContext.getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT);
```

You can also set the context from bootstrap in the class that you are using the app context.

```
YourClassName.setContext(appContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here, but I think that doWithWebDescriptor is used to generate the web.xml file. This file is necessary to start up the application. If your application is not up, you can't have a spring context yet.